# Probability and Statistics (Quartiles)

Tags: probability, statistics

Q: Find the upper and lower quartiles of the random variable.

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x\ln(1.5)}$$

for $4≤x≤6$

I set $F(x) = 0.25$ and $F(x) = 0.75$ to denote $Q1$ and $Q3$

This is what I got for the answers:

For $$F(X) = 0.25, x = 9.86$$
For $$F(X) = 0.75,  x = 3.28$$

However, these answers are wrong as compared with my textbook. 
It should be:

For $$F(X) = 0.25, x = 4.43$$
For $$F(X) = 0.75,  x = 5.42$$

Please help me. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Presumably $f(x)$ is the density of the random variable; otherwise the question does not make sense. You did not say what function you thought $F(x)$ was. Based on your results, my guess is you set $F(x) = f(x)$. In fact you need to define $F(x)$ so that $f(x) = F'(x)$. You should not even have to look in your textbook to know your answers are wrong: based on the given density, the random variable should be between $4$ and $6$ with probability $1$, whereas your answer says the variable is less than $3.28$ about 25% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

For $x$ between $4$ and $6$ we have
$$F(x)=\Pr(X\le x)=\int_4^x \frac{1}{\ln(1.5)t}\,dt=\frac{1}{\ln(1.5)}(\ln x-\ln 4).$$
For the first quartile $q_1$, we want
$$\frac{1}{\ln(1.5)}(\ln(q_1)-\ln 4)=0.25.$$
To solve, note that the above equation is equivalent to 
$$\ln(q_1/4)=(0.25)\ln(1.5).$$
Equivalently,
$$\frac{q_1}{4}=\exp((0.25)\ln(1.5))=(1.5)^{0.25}.$$
We get $q_1\approx 4.427$. I am sure you can now take care of $q_3$.